# Select from a Temp table is giving slow performance

Tags: sql, sql-server, temp-tables, sql-server-2019

I need some help with the below query where the last step of

```
Select * from #PersonDetail order by....
```

is taking so long to execute - why?

There are millions of records being inserted in this temp table `#PersonDetail` and insert process takes a few seconds, but the last `Select` from this same temp table is taking so long.

I created a unique clustered index on the columns used for order by and tried many other options but it doesn't make any difference in the performance.

It is a big stored procedure with many temp table but it is this last select step which is impacting the performance. Here is an example of the last step of the query:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #PersonDetail

CREATE TABLE #PersonDetail
( 
    PersonId INT NOT NULL,
    Name NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    Number INT NOT NULL,
    Tag NVARCHAR(50) NULL,
    UserId INT NOT NULL,
    NumberEncrypted VARCHAR(100),
    Type NVARCHAR(255),
    Status NVARCHAR(50),
    CreatedDate DATETIMEOFFSET(7),
    AddressDetailId NVARCHAR(50),
    Category NVARCHAR(50),
    PrimaryId INT,
    DailyAmount MONEY,
    
    UNIQUE (PersonId UserId),
    UNIQUE CLUSTERED(CreatedDate, UserId)
)
        
INSERT INTO #PersonDetail (PersonId, Name, Number, Tag, UserId, NumberEncrypted, 
                           Type, Status, CreatedDate, AddressDetailId, Category, PrimaryId, Amount)
    SELECT                                      
        PersonId, Name, Number, Tag, UserId, NumberEncrypted, 
        Type, Status, CreatedDate, AddressDetailId, Category, PrimaryId, DailyAmount            
    FROM 
        #User u    
    JOIN 
        dbo.DailyAmount da (NOLOCK) ON da.UserId = u.UserId
        
SELECT *
FROM #PersonDetail pd
ORDER BY CreatedDate, UserId
```

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @Jarlh - using sql server 2019

Comment: In SSMS, show client statistics - it is quite possible that most of the time is spent in transit (slow network).

Comment: @Arvo - ClientProcessing time -21617 and TotalExecutionTime - 21646. What are these values? Sorry not sure how ClientStatistiics work. Is this time in seconds?

Comment: Rather in milliseconds. I would say that ClientProcessing time includes network traffic and other not SQL server relates times - in your case SQL execution time is 21646-21617=29 milliseconds; this means that you don't need to optimise SQL, because most of the time is not SQL related at all. How many bytes were transferred? How fast is your network link?

Comment: Client Execution Time 03:55:13    Bytes sent from client 75984  75984.0000
  Bytes received from server 8.472971E+08  847297100.0000

Comment: Thanks @Arvo. I was not even thinking about Client execution time. I am not running the queries on the main server but on my local box.

Comment: If you want performance help you need to provide an execution plan.

Comment: Well, you are receiving almost a gigabyte of data - it takes time even over a fast network. If you queried this data just for testing, use `top 1000` or something; if you need further process it locally, then nothing to do. If you need process it on the server, then client time doesn't matter.

Comment: If you're going to [splatter nolock hints in your code](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere) you should AT LEAST use the current, non-deprecated syntax.

Answer (score -2):

You must specify what database are you using.

In general, you must do theese things:

- create some indexes on the join columns (DailyAmount.userId, User.userID); how to create the index must change;
- create an index on the order by columns, (CreatedDate+UserID); this must change, in postgresql for example an index with the 2 column is better than 2 indexes;

If your data are not changing frequently, you could try materialized view and create the indexes on the materialized view.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am using SQL Server 2019. Already created one CLUSTERED INDEX on both columns CreatedDate and UserId . Would the indexing on the tables used for inserting data in this TempTable affect the performance on the select from the same TempTable?

Comment: I am facing the same issue, any luck @Coder_GK?